# nginx redirect with dns name

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, redirect

I have nginx redirect like:

```
server {                                                                                                         
      listen       127.0.0.1:80;                                                                                 
      server_name  myname.local
      location / {                                                                                               
          proxy_pass http://m1.local:8080;                                                               
          }                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                            
}
```

Works good.

But after ip address for m1.local was changed - nginx start to return "bad gateway".

Looks like it has caching ip address for m1.local.

nslookup m1.local from nginx computer show right value, and restart nginx repair the situation.

How to say nginx that it shouldn't cache ip's for dns name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution here:

http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,238835,238899#msg-238899

```
location / {
set $backend "m1.local";
proxy_pass http://$backend;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nginx is doing these name lookups on start, and then it only keeps the IPs. This means that it won't even keep the names in memory during run time to look them up again.

If you change the DNS entries that you refer to in the Nginx conf, you can do an `nginx -s reload` to make it reload the config, this includes redoing the DNS lookups.

Comment: Yep. I sure you right, but it is not helps. This ip changed not by me, by another proccess, so I never know when do "reload".